# Which version of JUnit is compatible with JDK 1.3?

Tags: java, junit

For a legacy project I have to work with JDK 1.3. Since I want to add some unit tests I'd like to know which is the latest JUnit release I can use for this project.

Comment: update your jdk to 1.7 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since junit `4.x` is annotation based (but also supports the old style) it requires at least `jdk 1.5`, for `jdk 1.3` you need to go with junit `3.x`. See [here](http://www.asjava.com/junit/junit-3-vs-junit-4-comparison/).

> **1. JDK Required?**
>
> JUnit 4 requires Java 5 or higher, it uses a lot from Java 5 annotations, generics, and static import features.  the JUnit 3.x version can work with JDK 1.2+ and any higher versions.

Answer (score 0):

Having Googled the matter, JUnit 3.4 seems be compatible with JDK 1.3

Comment: How did you ask google? I'm asking here since I didn't find anything usefull.

Comment: I just made a search with the following keywords: "junit java 1.3". Just take some time to scroll among the results and you'll find interesting info. For instance, it seems that JUnit 3.8.2 were not compatible with JDK 1.3